# C# Selenium webdriver timeout callback? How to quit the driver if it times out?

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

Fairly straight forward question, how do I handle timeouts? I want to set a new proxy and try again, but just quitting will be sufficient.

```
driver.Manage().Timeouts().SetPageLoadTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(aURL);
```

I'm using chrome driver. Currently when it times out the page becomes in active, is there a way I can query the state of the page to see if it's 'dead' after this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put a `try-catch` around the `.GoToUrl()` call, catch the timeout exception and then set your new proxy and try again.